# Django queryset reversing ways

Tags: django, django-queryset

I know two ways to reverse ordered queryset:

```
qs.objects.filter(**cond).order_by('-field_name')
```

and

```
qs.objects.filter(**cond).order_by('field_name').reverse()
```

Is there any appropriate case (except of tempates) to use second way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an appropriate case, from what I understand `qs.objects.filter(**cond).order_by('-field_name')` is done at the database level, so it will outperform calling reverse on the queryset.